# Wrong cummulative distribution obtained from integrating the PDF

Tags: python, scipy, cdf

I have a PDF (code below) and I'm trying to obtain it's [cummulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF). I can use the standard approach of integrating the PDF from 0. (it's minimum allowed value) to increasing `x` values. This works as expected:

[image]

where the PDF is in red and the "stepwise" CDF in blue. But this leaves me with a table of `(x, y)` data, and I want the actual *function*  that describes this CDF. So I turn to integrating the PDF from 0. up to a variable `y` to obtain this expression. I do this [with WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28x%5Eb%29%20*%20exp%28c%20*%20x%29%20from%200%20to%20y) (WA) and I find:

[image]

I write this function into my code using the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html) and I get this:

[image]

where the WA integrated CDF is in orange. I tried the lower incomplete gamma function but the results are worse.

I'm pretty sure the WA CDF is written without mistakes, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma, gammaincc
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    xx = np.linspace(0., 5., 100)
    yy = PDF(xx)
    plt.plot(xx, yy, c='r')

    # Find stepwise CDF
    cummul = []
    for x in xx:
        cummul.append([x, integrate.quad(PDF, 0., x)[0]])
    plt.plot(*np.array(cummul).T)

    # WolframAlpha's integral
    y = CDF(xx)
    plt.plot(xx, y)


def PDF(y):
    a = (343. / 15.) * np.sqrt(7. / (2. * np.pi))
    b, c = 5. / 2., -7. / 2.
    return a * (y ** b) * np.exp(c * y)


def CDF(x):
    """
    From WolframAlpha
    """
    a = (343. / 15.) * np.sqrt(7. / (2. * np.pi))
    b, c = 5. / 2., -7. / 2.
    return a * (
        x**b * (-c * x)**(-b) * (gammaincc(b + 1, -c * x) - b * gamma(b))) / c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scipy.special.gammaincc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html) is the *regularized* upper incomplete gamma function.  If the  incomplete gamma function is gamma(a, x), then the reqularized incomplete gamma function is gamma(a, x)/gamma(a).  The incomplete gamma function in the WA formula is not the regularized version.  You'll get the expected result if you multiply `gammaincc(b + 1, -c * x)` by `gamma(b + 1)`.  That is, change the return statement to

```
    return a * (
        x**b * (-c * x)**(-b) * (gamma(b + 1) * gammaincc(b + 1, -c * x) - b * gamma(b))) / c
```

which can also be written

```
    return a * (
        x**b * (-c * x)**(-b) * gamma(b + 1) * (gammaincc(b + 1, -c * x) - 1)) / c
```

If I use the latter version, and change the plot of the Wolfram Alpha integral to

```
    plt.plot(xx, y, '--', linewidth=4, alpha=0.6)
```

I get this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Excellent answer Warren, thank you! I need to pay more attention to those little details in `scipy`'s pre-defined functions.